# How to compare averages with different sample sizes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, statistics

I have a need to compare the average number of sales that are cash sales from one year to another. For example, in 2016 there were 198 sales, of which 5 were cash (avg. = 2%). This year so far there were 41 sales and 2 were cash sales (avg. = 5%). I am reluctant to report that average cash sales are up this year mostly because I don't know if the difference is statistically significant with the sample sizes being different. I think I need to do a t-test or something similar but I am not an expert.

Would it be sufficient to say that average cash sales are up? Something like:

```
var trend = ( ( avgCashSalesThisYear - avgCashSalesLastYear ) * 100 ).toFixed( 0 );
```

Comment: This seems to be about statistical analysis, which is off topic here. Once yo have an algorithm, come here with help to implement it. You should compare with the equivalent period from last year, not the whole year as a single number doesn't give you either trend or seasonal effects (so the reliability of any analysis is pretty low).

Comment: Precisely. I am looking for a way to generate a statistic in JavaScript. Can you let me know why it might be off topic so I can revise?

Comment: The types of questions that are on-topic are in the help centre under [*What topics can I ask about here?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You can ask about software algorithms, but here you seem to be asking for a statistical analysis algorithm. Once you know the algorithm you want to implement, then it becomes an exercise to develop an equivalent software algorithm. I hope that makes sense. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can take last years numbers as truth because you measured it already. Take the ratio of cash transactions to total and call this lambda. This year you would expect to see a number of cash transactions that would follow a Poisson distribution. The lambda for the current year to date would be last years lambda times the total to date this year. I'll call that lambda2.

The Poisson probability for seeing k cash events is

```
Prob(k) = Pow(Lambda2 , k)* pow(e, -k) / k!
```

K! Is 1*2*3*... *k

e is a constant 2.718.

So add prob(1)+prob(2)+... prob(nCashThisYear-1)

This sum is the probability of seeing a lower number of cash events based on last years data. Add in prob(nCashThisYear) to get the probability of having less than or equal to what was observed.  Subtract that from 1 to get the probability of a higher number of cases.